# replace default application.conf file in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, datastax

My code works like:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load
```

It gets the key-value pairs from **application.conf** by default. Then I use -Dconfig.file= to point to another conf file.

It works fine for command below:

```
dse -u cassandra -p cassandra spark-submit 
    --class packagename.classname --driver-java-options 
    -Dconfig.file=/home/userconfig.conf /home/user-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

But now I need to split the **userconfig.conf** to 2 files. I tried command below. It doesn't work.

```
dse -u cassandra -p cassandra spark-submit 
    --class packagename.classname --driver-java-options 
    -Dconfig.file=/home/userconfig.conf,env.conf 
     /home/user-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

By default spark will look in defaults.conf but you can 1) specify another file using 'properties-file'  2) you can pass individual keu value properties using --conf or 3) you can set up the configuration programmatically in your code using the sparkConf object

Does this help or are you looking for the akka application.conf file?

Comment: I didn't get your point. I have code like (val config = ConfigFactory.load) to get k-v pairs from application.conf.
Then I use -Dconfig.file= to replace the default application.conf. Now I want to split the setting into 2 conf files.